# Why I'm taking httpStatus:401 or httpStatus 500 with HttpUrlConnection Java?

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, http-status-codes

I'm try to post request with HttpURLConnection

This is request body:

[image]

This is request header:

[image]

This is my Code:

```
public static String postSms(long mNo,long cepNo, String mesaj){
        
        
        String responseLine = null;
        String url = getSmsUrl();
        String authKey = getSmsAuthKey();
        
                try {
            
            URL s_url = new URL(url);
            httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) s_url.openConnection();           
            if(authKey != null){
                httpCon.setRequestProperty("yd-x-token", authKey);  
            }
            httpCon.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; utf-8");
            httpCon.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
            int responseCode = httpCon.getResponseCode();
            if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                JSONObject msj = new JSONObject();          
                msj.put("toNumber", cepNo);
                msj.put("smsText", mesaj);
                
                try(OutputStream os = httpCon.getOutputStream()) {
                    byte[] input = msj.toString().getBytes("utf-8");
                    os.write(input, 0, input.length);           
                }           
                try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                          new InputStreamReader(httpCon.getInputStream(), "utf-8"))) {
                            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                             responseLine = null;
                            while ((responseLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                                response.append(responseLine.trim());
                            }
                        }
            }else return "ER|[sendNotification][Sms] <===> "+responseCode;            
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            log.error("ER|[sendNotification][Sms] <===> Hata "+e);
            return "ER|[sendNotification][Sms] <===> Hata "+e;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("ER|[sendNotification][Sms] <===> Hata "+e);
            return "ER|[sendNotification][Sms] <===> Hata "+e;
        }catch (JSONException e){

       }
         return "OK";

        }
```

When i try postman like two photos, it's happens successs. But when i try with HttpURLConnection, response code = 500 . Sometimes responseCode was coming 401 but when they give new token that changes with httpstatus 500. Why I'm getting this error.

Comment: Why are you writing your request body input only `if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)`? You're basically doing an empty request and then try to write input to an already consumed connection.

Comment: @Thomas where should  I take the responseCode ?  before try(BufferredReader .... ) block ?

Comment: Basically yes, you need to write the request body (and headers) before trying to get the response code because the request will need to get executed to get that code. You probably got the 401 when you sent an anvalid token because only the headers have been checked (and you sent those) whereas when the token is valid the body needs to be evaluated and since you didn't send any that's a server error (could be handled to return a 400 instead but the devs probably didn't think about this)

Answer (score 0):

If you get a status 401, it means you don't have permission for access this URL. This is why they gave you a new token, you got a status 500. So make sure that you always have right token before calling that request.
For the status 500, It is an issue of server side. Tell your server developer, check it.
By the way, It is stupid url with ".json" at the end.

Answer (score -1):

True way is :

public static String postSms(long mNo,long cepNo, String mesaj){

```
    String responseLine = null;
    String url = getSmsUrl();
    String authKey = getSmsAuthKey();
    
            try {
        
        URL s_url = new URL(url);
        httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) s_url.openConnection();           
        if(authKey != null){
            httpCon.setRequestProperty("yd-x-token", authKey);  
        }
        httpCon.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; utf-8");
        httpCon.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
       
            JSONObject msj = new JSONObject();          
            msj.put("toNumber", cepNo);
            msj.put("smsText", mesaj);
            
            try(OutputStream os = httpCon.getOutputStream()) {
                byte[] input = msj.toString().getBytes("utf-8");
                os.write(input, 0, input.length);           
            }           
        int responseCode = httpCon.getResponseCode();
        if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
            try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                      new InputStreamReader(httpCon.getInputStream(), "utf-8"))) {
                        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                         responseLine = null;
                        while ((responseLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            response.append(responseLine.trim());
                        }
                    }
        }else return "ER|[sendNotification][Sms] <===> "+responseCode;            
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        log.error("ER|[sendNotification][Sms] <===> Hata "+e);
        return "ER|[sendNotification][Sms] <===> Hata "+e;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("ER|[sendNotification][Sms] <===> Hata "+e);
        return "ER|[sendNotification][Sms] <===> Hata "+e;
    }catch (JSONException e){

   }
     return "OK";

    }
```